# Swift. Layer with UIVisualEffect overlaps the screen so that the user is blocked from doing interactions

Tags: ios, swift, cell, uivisualeffectview

I create object UIVisualEffect, and under him I have some cells in CollectionView, so cells is scrolling by finger.

But when I add layer with object UIVisualEffect, I can't make any gestures on cells.

UIVisualEffect layer is overlap all.

How to make possible do any gestures by finger through UIVisualEffect objects ?

Comment: Do `visualEffectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Um! Worked! But how? Can you explain please @aheze ? Code ask - Is User Interaction Enabled, and we declare - false, what it seem to be we prohibit interaction with the screen. So how is it works in this case ???

Comment: (I'm a beginner)

Comment: You’re disabling it for the blur view only, not the entire screen. So the blur view won’t receive touches, and they get forwarded to underlying views